If cell contains specific multiple words then
I need a line of code that looks at the cell and if it contains a set of words then it does something else:
If Range("A1").Value = "*Tree*" or "*Plant*" or "*Grass*" Then
'does something
else
'does something else
End If

I know this isn't the right code to achieve what I want but I cannot find the correct way to do this anywhere.

You can use Like
Dim v, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'try to always use a specific sheet
v = LCase(ws.Range("A1").Value) 'lower-case for comparisons, unless case is important

If v Like "*tree*" or v Like "*plant*" or v Like "*grass*" Then
'does something
else
'does something else
End If

Note this would not distinguish between (eg) "tree" and "treehouse", but it's not clear if you need to check for whole words only.
A more re-useable version using a function and Instr:
Sub tester()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = "this sentence contains some words"
    Debug.Print ContainsAny(txt, "dog", "horse", "some") '>> True
    Debug.Print ContainsAny(txt, "dog", "horse")         '>> False
End Sub

'Returns True if `txt` contains any of the words passed to `words`
Function ContainsAny(txt As String, ParamArray words()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
        If InStr(1, txt, words(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ContainsAny = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function

